# How to set same color and legend for ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, color

```
conn = {{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {10, 10}}, {{10, 0}, {10, 10}}, 
       {{10, 0}, {20, 0}}, {{10, 10}, {20, 0}}, {{10, 10}, {20, 10}}, 
       {{20, 0}, {20, 10}}, {{20, 0}, {30, 0}}, {{20, 10}, {30, 0}}};

ListLinePlot[conn, PlotStyle -> Dashing[Large]]
```

I am new to *Mathematica*. I want all the lines to be of the same color (say red). I tried different options, but they are not consistent with `ListLinePlot`. I also want to legend the whole structure as a single entity as I am having multiple structures in the same plot. Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: Lots of ways to do what you want, e.g. `Flatten[conn, 1]`  or `Join@@conn` in `ListLinePlot`. Then just use `PlotLegends` as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want might be satisfied by something as simple as

```
ListLinePlot[conn,
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[Large]}},
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Entity"}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm getting the PlotStyle but I'm getting the following error everytime I use PlotLegend:                           ListLinePlot::optx: Unknown option PlotLegends in ListLinePlot[{{{0,0},{10,0}},{{0,0},{10,10}},{{10,0},{10,10}},{{10,0},{20,0}},{{10,10},{20,0}},{{10,10},{20,10}},{{20,0},{20,10}},{{20,0},{30,0}},{{20,10},{30,0}}},PlotStyle->{{RGBColor[1,0,0],Dashing[Large]}},PlotLegends->LineLegend[{Entity}]]. >>

Comment: @Indu. What version of _Mathematica_ are you using? `PlotLegends` and `LineLegend` became available in V9.0.

Comment: I'm using V8.0 Is there a way to solve this problem in this version?

Comment: In V8 there is a Plot Legends package you can load with `Needs`. It's not as capable or as easy to use as the current `PlotLegends` option, but I think it can do what are you are looking for. I don't have V8 available, so I can't produce a V8 validated answer to your question. Here are two references that should help: [guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/guide/PlotLegendsPackage.html); [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/tutorial/PlotLegends.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but here's my approach:

```
ListLinePlot[conn
 , PlotStyle ->
  {
   {Red, Dashing[{3, 3}/100]}
   , {Red, Dashing[Tiny]}
   }
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]